# Typing Chinese character in the main site

Tags: bug, status-completed

The question [Followup to "How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258911/followup-to-how-does-one-type-chinese-in-latex) raises an interesting problem. If one tries to paste the code by Leo Liu in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17637/4427), pop up boxes saying

> Body cannot contain "??".

---

[image: Quack]

---

where in place of `??` the first used Chinese character appears.

Trying to add Chinese characters in comments results in

> Comments cannot contain that content.

---

[image: Quack]

---

The first Chinese character is U+6587, which, according to Google Translate, means “culture”, so it doesn't seem to bear offensive or disputable meaning. If I remove it, the second character triggers similar messages. Again according to Google Translate, the sequence

```
U+6587 U+7AE0 U+5185 U+5BB9
```

simply means “Article content”.

I can paste the characters in the code examples in other program windows; the same if I try copying and pasting the characters in the resulting PDF file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have has a spate of Chinese spam across the network - quite persistent too.

As result we have taken the temporary measure of disallowing all Chinese characters across the network (barring the few sites where they are expected - Chinese language, Japanese language as well and Anime & Manga, for example).

We will remove the block once we see the spam attempts stop.

The last recorded attempt was ~24 hours ago.

---

The block has been hit once again, two days ago. Looking at what has been blocked, most were legitimate posts.

So, I've lifted the block.

Comment: Was there an announcement somewhere?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. We manage spam block continually. We also don't want to tip spammers to what we do.

Comment: It's quite annoying not being able to type in legitimate posts for unknown reasons, even if those reasons are good.

Comment: I appreciate that - it is annoying, but we do not currently have a better way to block these Chinese spammers. The decision was taken to block them on sites that have little reason to legitimately use Chinese characters.

Comment: Could we, please, trigger the spam filter only for low-rep users?

Comment: @yo' - that is not functionality we currently have. I am not sure that this would be the right approach either.

Comment: @Oded Do you experience spam floods from users with 400+k reputation?! I understand that "not implemented" is a reason, but I don't see what's wrong with the approach. After all, wasn't image uploading and linking limited in the same way some not so long time ago?

Comment: @yo' - just saying that there may be better approaches. Tim Post is looking into better anti-spam tools.

Comment: @Oded, could the linguistics.se site also benefit from the special regime, I had to [make a bitmap](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11373/interrogatives-and-copulas-in-malay/13055#13055) to workaround the issue? Thanks.

Comment: @AlainPannetier - I removed the block on linguistics. It was only hit twice ever. Probably both times were you. You should be able to replace the image now.

Comment: Please see my comment in the code block. [How to insert Chinese characters in the following template?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261042)

Comment: Is the block on Chinese text on again?  I cannot post a source file with a paragraph of Chinese text in it.

Comment: @zzjing - yes, looks like it was reinstated early November and was triggered 50 times since (which includes your attempt)

Comment: @zzjing - I looked at our logs, and pretty much all 50 are legitimate uses, so I removed the block.