# Chinese character limit on this site

Tags: support

It seems that there's a limit to the number of Chinese characters you can put in a post.  I understand it's an anti-spam feature.  Now how do I post a LaTeX source file with a short paragraph of Chinese text in it?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/typing-chinese-character-in-the-main-site/6252#6252 When chinese spam come across the SE network, mods limit the amount of chinese characters per post

Comment: Well, I saw that, but it doesn't help me.  I guess I'm out of luck then.

Answer (score 2):

[The block has been removed](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/typing-chinese-character-in-the-main-site/6252#comment18859_6252). Thanks, Oded.